# Bigdecimal operation

Tags: kotlin, bigdecimal

why does decrement result -0.8?
What is the logic?

```
import java.math.BigDecimal
fun main(){
    var first = BigDecimal("0.2")
    val decrement = --first
    println(decrement) //-0.8
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--` operator is added by Kotlin onto BigDecimal:  https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/java.math.-big-decimal/dec.html

For completeness `--` means reduce the value by 1, which is why `0.2 - 1 = -0.8`.  `--` is normally used with integers, but it seems Kotlin has extended it for BigDecimal too.